# Postgresql query XMLTable with default namespace

Tags: xml, postgresql-12

I use PostgreSQL 12 to query XML data.

My data is as below

```
CREATE TABLE xmldata AS SELECT
xml $$
<ROWS xmlns="http://x.y.z">
  <ROW id="1">
    <COUNTRY_ID>AU</COUNTRY_ID>
    <COUNTRY_NAME>Australia</COUNTRY_NAME>
  </ROW>
  <ROW id="5">
    <COUNTRY_ID>JP</COUNTRY_ID>
    <COUNTRY_NAME>Japan</COUNTRY_NAME>
    <PREMIER_NAME>Shinzo Abe</PREMIER_NAME>
    <SIZE unit="sq_mi">145935</SIZE>
  </ROW>
  <ROW id="6">
    <COUNTRY_ID>SG</COUNTRY_ID>
    <COUNTRY_NAME>Singapore</COUNTRY_NAME>
    <SIZE unit="sq_km">697</SIZE>
  </ROW>
</ROWS>
$$ AS data;
```

When query, my SQL is as below:

```
SELECT xmltable.*
  FROM xmldata,
       XMLTABLE(namespaces(default 'http://x.y.z'), '//ROWS/ROW'
                PASSING data
                COLUMNS id int PATH '@id',
                        ordinality FOR ORDINALITY,
                        "COUNTRY_NAME" text,
                        country_id text PATH 'COUNTRY_ID',
                        size_sq_km float PATH 'SIZE[@unit = "sq_km"]',
                        size_other text PATH
                             'concat(SIZE[@unit!="sq_km"], " ", SIZE[@unit!="sq_km"]/@unit)',
                        premier_name text PATH 'PREMIER_NAME' DEFAULT 'not specified') ;
```

It happened this error:

```
DEFAULT namespace is not supported
```

Please instruct how to fix it ?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As [documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-PROCESSING-XMLTABLE) "*A default namespace specification is not currently supported*"

You need to give the namespace an alias and use that in the XPath expressions:

```
SELECT xmltable.*
FROM xmldata,
     XMLTABLE(
        xmlnamespaces('http://x.y.z' as x),
        '//x:ROWS/x:ROW'
        PASSING data
        COLUMNS 
          id int PATH '@id',
          ordinality FOR ORDINALITY,
          "x:COUNTRY_NAME" text,
          country_id text PATH 'x:COUNTRY_ID',
          size_sq_km float PATH 'x:SIZE[@unit = "sq_km"]',
          size_other text PATH 
                     'concat(x:SIZE[@unit!="sq_km"], " ", x:SIZE[@unit!="sq_km"]/@unit)',
          premier_name text PATH 'x:PREMIER_NAME' DEFAULT 'not specified'
     ) ;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8e68a22a6efff1a417eca04ffe8563e4)